# How could I Checkout to Already downloaded project

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have already downloaded whole project files but without svn folders/files. How could I update/checkout it from link to repository to get svn?

SVN is trying to download and replace every file I'm already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the --force flag does exactly what you want.

```
cd your_work_dir
svn checkout --force URL .
```

the help command

```
svn help checkout
```

gives:

> If --force is used, unversioned obstructing paths in the working
>   copy destination do not automatically cause the check out to fail.
>   If the obstructing path is the same type (file or directory) as the
>   corresponding path in the repository it becomes versioned but its
>   contents are left 'as-is' in the working copy.  This means that an
>   obstructing directory's unversioned children may also obstruct and
>   become versioned.  For files, any content differences between the
>   obstruction and the repository are treated like a local modification
>   to the working copy.  All properties from the repository are applied
>   to the obstructing path.

Safest option is to do a new checkout with destination directory.
You can specify the destination directory in second argument:

```
svn checkout URL[@REV] [PATH]
```

exemple

```
svn checkout http://your_svn_server/project/trunk proj_wc
```

Maybe another option (not sure what it will really do) is :

```
svn checkout --depth=empty URL
```

to get just the .svn datas.
You can then just list what to checkout with command

```
svn list
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `svn checkout` against the existing files. If these files are identical to the youngest revision in the repository, Subversion won't fetch them again and you will get fully-functional working copy.

Otherwise just perform clean checkout from the repository.